# Highcharts create custom button in config

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to leverage the Highcharts config object to create a custom button w/o using the export feature?

The method below will programatically add the button w/the last few lines of code (prior to the return statement), however I'd like to simply take care of this in the config.

```
    var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: container,
                zoomType: 'x',
                spacingBottom: 20,
                type: 'column'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                align: 'right'
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                crosshairs: true,
                xDateFormat: '%b %e, %l:%M %p'
            },
            series: [
                { 
                    "name": "Excellent",
                    "color": config.color.excellent,
                    "data": dataE,
                    "pointWidth": pointWidth ? pointWidth : undefined
                },
                { 
                    "name": "Fair",
                    "color": config.color.fair,
                    "data": dataF,
                    "pointWidth": pointWidth ? pointWidth : undefined 
                },
                { 
                    "name": "Poor",
                    "color": config.color.poor,
                    "data": dataP,
                    "pointWidth": pointWidth ? pointWidth : undefined 
                }
            ],
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }

        // Adds new button below
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        var custombutton = chart.renderer.button('button', 74, 10, function(){
            alert('New Button Pressed');
        },null,null,null).add();
        return chart;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible without the exporting module, but you can use that module and define your own customs buttons which will have nothing in common with the exporting feature.

```
exporting: {
        buttons: [{
          text: 'custom button',
          onclick: function () {
            alert('clicked');
          },
          theme: {
                'stroke-width': 1,
                stroke: 'silver',
                r: 0,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fill: '#a4edba'
                    },
                    select: {
                        stroke: '#039',
                        fill: '#a4edba'
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/upt4cbqj/

You can also extend Highcharts with the new config options which will allow you to define buttons in the options without the exporting module. More information about extending Highcharts [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts).